# How show minutes and seconds with Stopwatch()

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I need to show also the minutes, actually I use this code for show the seconds, but also need the minutes

```
TimeSpan ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;
Console.WriteLine("File Generated: " + _writer.getBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)) + " in "  + "{0}.{1:D2}" + "seconds", 
    ts.Seconds, 
    ts.Milliseconds/10 + "\n"
);
```

how can I do?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("File Generated: " + _writer.getBinaryFileName(filePath, Convert.ToInt32(logSelected)) + " in: "  + " {0} minute(s)"+ " {1} second(s)",
                        ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds/10 + "\n");

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer that worked best for you, ale. Just to keep the unanswered questions section "clean". Thank you! :)

Comment: what is stopwatch?

Comment: @barlop Stopwatch "Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time." See here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 95):

You should use:

```
ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff")
```

this will give you minutes, seconds and the hundredths of a second in a time interval.

also take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

**EDITED:**
well if you want minutes be your biggest unit you can do the following:

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalMinutes), ts.ToString("ss\\.ff"))
```

Comment: The problem, though, is if the total timespan is 70 minutes, it will show `10:00.00`.

Comment: Using string interpolation and format specifier: `$"Total processing time: {Math.Floor(ts.TotalMinutes)}:{ts:ss\\.ff}"`

Answer (score 28):

The [TimeSpan.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) method in .NET 4.0 has an overload that lets you specify the format.

To display minutes and seconds:

```
TimeSpan elapsed = GetElapsedTime(); // however you get the amount of time elapsed
string tsOut = elapsed.ToString(@"m\:ss");
```

To include the milliseconds, you would write:

```
string tsOut = elapsed.ToString(@"m\:ss\.ff");
```

Note, however, that this won't do what you expect if the total timespan is more than 60 minutes. The "minutes" value displayed will be `elapsed.Minutes`, which is basically the same as `((int)elapsed.TotalMinutes) % 60)`. So if the total time was 70 minutes, the above will show `10:00`.

If you want to show the total minutes and seconds reliably, you have to do the math yourself.

```
int minutes = (int)elapsed.TotalMinutes;
double fsec = 60 * (elapsed.TotalMinutes - minutes);
int sec = (int)fsec;
int ms = 1000 * (fsec - sec);
string tsOut = String.Format("{0}:{1:D2}.{2}", minutes, sec, ms);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but "int ms = 1000 * (fsec - sec);" is wrong.

Comment: @NorbertBoros Explain your reasoning. Better yet, write a little test program to verify your assertion, and show me the results.

Comment: I believe it is pretty clear, error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?).

Answer (score 23):

I've coded this way:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...

Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

// here the complex program.
...

watch.Stop();

TimeSpan timeSpan = watch.Elapsed;

Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}h {1}m {2}s {3}ms", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: use timeSpan.TotalHours,

Answer (score 9):

//try it

```
       Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(10382);

        sw.Stop();


        Console.Write(sw.Elapsed.Duration());
```

Answer (score 8):

Review the [documentation for `TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), the struct returned by `stopwatch.Elapsed`. You want either the `Minutes` or `TotalMinutes` property.

If you're measuring a 62 minute span, `ts.Minutes` will return `2`, and `ts.TotalMinutes` will return `62`.

Comment: Have to be careful, though. If the total time span is 62 minutes and 30 seconds, `ts.TotalMinutes` will return `62.5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeTakenOutput.Text = "0" + myStopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString() 
 + ":" + myStopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + "mins";
```

Answer (score -3):

```
ts.Minutes
```

Comment: for the seconds is this {0}.{1:D2}, which is for the minutes??

Comment: You could use `{0}:{1}.{2:D2}`